# IISHttpServer OnDisconnect NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

While running a .NET Core web application that is primarily based on executing Endpoints, I frequently get a `NullReferenceException` on the `AbortIO` call following a call to `context.Response.Redirect(url, false)` in my code.

Anyone have any ideas?

For example, the following code :

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/someurl", async context => {
        context.Response.Redirect("/someotherurl", false);
    });
});
```

Often errors here because `context` is null:

```
private static void OnDisconnect(IntPtr pvManagedHttpContext)
{
    IISHttpContext context = null;
    try
    {
        context = (IISHttpContext)GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pvManagedHttpContext).Target;
        context.AbortIO(clientDisconnect: true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context?.Server._logger.LogError(0, ex, $"Unexpected exception in {nameof(IISHttpServer)}.{nameof(OnDisconnect)}.");
    }
}
```

Source: [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Servers/IIS/IIS/src/Core/IISHttpServer.cs#L173), line 173

Comment: You're possibly hitting this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17516

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: Something that worked for me was using the command `dotnet run` instead of debug with the IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed by the .net team: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17516